# When debugging unit tests in Visual Studio, is there a way to dynamically attach to a running web application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to debug a C# Web API. The Web API code is running autonomously in IIS on my machine (it is not launched by Visual Studio). It lives at `localhost\myProject\api\` and takes basic parameters passed by a JavaScript frontend.

I am debugging using a C# Unit Test project that runs server-side and makes calls to the Web API. When I run "debug tests", the tests are started with the debugger, but no symbols for the targeted Web Api are loaded and I need to attach to the Web API process manually every time I run a test.

Is there a way for Visual Studio to dynamically associate Unit Tests with a running application so that I don't need to manually attach the debugger to the corresponding process for every test run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would not need to attach to IIS for running a Unit Test. Your Web API Endpoint should be calling into code that you can reach from your Unit Test without calling the Web API from your test.

I am not sure if what you want to do is possible, but if you can build a layer between your API call and your code, you can test and debug those tests much easier.

Comment: I see, this makes sense. So right now I have an ApiController with a Get() method that I'm testing directly with HTTP calls; I should just call it / its sub-methods directly with test methods? I have a number of sub-method tests but I was hoping to have at least one end-to-end test that verified that it can be hit by a real request.

Comment: Yes from Unit Test projects you want to only test against those sub methods. There are ways to do End-to-End testing, but those would generally not use the Unit Test project. You can use a tool like PostMan if you want to send in real requests without running through the UI.